# gnuplot wxt not working anymore

Tags: gnuplot

I have recently upgraded to Debian jessie, meaning that I have upgraded from gnuplot 4.6.0 to gnuplot 4.6.6 (issue is the same with gnuplot 5.0).

I have bash scripts automating things, and launching gnuplot terminal.

I was using either:

```
gnuplot -persist -e "set title 'Sine curve'; plot sin(x)"
```

or

```
gnuplot -persist <<EOF                                   
set title 'Sine curve'
plot sin(x)
EOF
```

The terminal `wxt` is no more distributed by debian (and derivatives like ubuntu), because of [#751441](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=751441).

I am using now terminal `qt`. It displays the plot, but that's the end. The window is static and most of the buttons do not work. I cannot zoom, I cannot unzoom, I cannot show the grid.

How to circumvent this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Answering my own question: I spent two much time googling, trying to understand why, reading excuses to not correct it, and finding workarounds.

***First***, you have to *remove* `-persist` because it has a `wxt` special way of working, and it is not the same way of working with `qt` terminal. See [#1418](https://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/bugs/1418/).

***Second***, you have to *add* "pause mouse close" after your plot. See [#1418](https://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/bugs/1418/). The script is now:

```
gnuplot -e "set title 'Sine curve'; plot sin(x); pause mouse close"
```

Now the zoom in, zoom out, and show grid are working.

***Third***, wait, you did not plotted a sinus, but `with lines`. Like this example:

```
$ gnuplot <<EOF
plot '-' using 1:2 t '' with line
0 0
10 10
e
pause mouse close
EOF
```

Now, if you zoom somewhere in the *middle of a segment*, you get nothing, an empty and blank screen. What you need is `set clip two` that tells to not clip when segments *ends* are not shown. See [#1419](https://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/bugs/1419/). So the following will work:

```
$ gnuplot <<EOF
set clip two
plot '-' using 1:2 t '' with line
0 0
10 10
e
pause mouse close
EOF
```

***Finally***, what I have done, is:

1. add `pause mouse close` at the end of the script
2. add `set clip two` in `~/.gnuplot` file

With this, I can mimic the `wxt` way of working while using `qt` terminal. IMHO, as a basic end-user, this should be the default.